# Distributed cache with expiration control in Java

Tags: java, caching, distributed

The requirement is to cache a large number (100,000 to 1,000,000) of small objects and control the expiration of individual objects based on future events.  There is no time component to the expiration.

The cache must be available to a number of application servers (SpringSource dm Server) and ideally should be distributable and error tolerant itself.

I have been looking at Terracotta as a possible solution.  Is that a good path to go down?  Is there a better one?

Comment: I might be understanding the question wrong, but if you control the CRUD and you control the cache, what's to stop you using *any* distributed cache (ehcache I believe is the crowd favourite) and then manually invalidating objects whenever you please? If there is no time component to expiration you either set the TTL/TTI very high (just in case some objects really should be thrown out after awhile) or turn it off completely.

Comment: We can use any distributed cache that gives us control to remove individual items via an external trigger.  I'm looking for experience and recommendations for the best solution.  According to ehcache.org, there is the potential for data inconsistency with a distributed EH Cache solution (for version 1.5).  Terracotta does not seem to have that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been using Terracotta and we're extremely happy with it.  Its Distributed Caches with the Cache Evictors were a great solution to our problems.

Comment: For cache invalidation, my understanding is that Terracotta will remove a row from cache if it is removed from the underlying DB, as long as the delete operation happens through Terracotta/Hibernate.  Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of deletions, I know writes are kept in sync as long as it goes through Hibernate.  This document may help you more: http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/orgsite/Terracotta+for+Hibernate+Reference+Guide

Comment: Eric, that's correct but it's not a feature of Terracotta, it's a feature of Hibernate, so any cache provider will be able to do that (as ehcache and Infinispan)

Answer (score 4):

I think the best option for you is JBoss Infinispan (http://www.jboss.org/infinispan).  The cache is stupid simple to setup, supports replication, eviction, persistence, among many other things.  More importantly, the cache works in your application server.  You can also access the cache using REST and there are abstractions for wiring Hibernate onto it.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the (more of less) new comers from the key-value world could be an alternative. If I understand correctly your requirements, memcached seams a natural fit, with a very small overhead. Client side consistent hashing will get you a reasonably good fault tolerancy.

Redis, Voldemort or Tokyo Tyrant can be relevant too, even if they more about storing than caching. Redis in particular has some very sexy features (list, set, atomic operations...)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered Memcached? You've mentioned small objects specifically: memcached is great in that regard. It's distributed and fault tolerant, very fast, open source, actively used and maintained everywhere, and has two great Java client APIs: Danga and Spy.

The only requirement of yours that memcached doesn't meet is the lack of a time component to object expiration. I believe the maximum of amount of time an object can spend in cache is 30 days. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, this would not meet the requirement, since expiration must be externally triggered and the objects must remain in the cache indefinitely until expired.